# What kind of knowledge or training is necessary for someone to write down the definition of foldlM like this?

Tags: haskell, higher-order-functions, fold

Recently, I am trying to use Haskell in some of my real case production system. The Haskell type system really offers me great help. For example, when I realised that I need some function of type

```
f :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => ( a-> b -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b
```

There are actually functions like `foldM`, `foldlM` and `foldrM`.

However, what real shocked me is the definition of these functions, such as:

```
foldlM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b
foldlM f z0 xs = foldr f' return xs z0
  where f' x k z = f z x >>= k
```

so  function `f'` must be of type:

```
f' :: a -> b -> b
```

as required by `foldr`, then `b` must be of kind `*-> m *`, so the entire definition of `foldlM` could make sense.

Another example includes definitions of `liftA2` and `<*>`

```
(<*>) :: f (a -> b) -> f a -> f b
(<*>) = liftA2 id

liftA2 :: (a -> b -> c) -> f a -> f b -> f c
liftA2 f x = (<*>) (fmap f x)
```

I tried some of my own solutions before peeking into the source code. But the gap is so huge that I don't think I could ever come up with this solution, no matter how many lines of code I will write in future.

So my question is, what kind of knowledge or which specific mathematics branch is necessary for someone to reasoning on such a highly abstracted level.

I know Category theory might offer some help and I've been following [this great lecture](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I8LbkfSSR58&list=PLbgaMIhjbmEnaH_LTkxLI7FMa2HsnawM_) for a long time and still working on it.

Comment: Haskell is a language.  It has many words, and most of those words can be used in a variety of different ways.  When you are learning a new language, for years many sentences and idioms don't make sense. But the more you use it, the more you see familiar patterns, and things you once thought were intimidating and advanced come quite naturally. Relax.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general, logic etc., I would imagine. But you can also learn it by doing it. :) With time you notice some patterns, pick up some tricks.

Like this `foldr` with an extra argument thing. Some see it as folding into functions so they can be combined through `.` and `id` (which [*sometimes*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Category.html#t:Category) are really [`<=<`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Control-Monad.html#v:-60--61--60-) and `return`),

```
foldr g z xs  =  foldr ($) z . map g $ xs
              =  foldr (.) id (map g xs) z
         ~/=  foldr (<=<) return (map g xs) z
{-
  (\f -> f . f) :: (a -> a) -> (a -> a)

  (\f -> f <=< f) :: Monad m => (a -> m a) -> (a -> m a)
                            (still just a type, not a kind)
-}
```

Some find it easier to understand it in simpler, syntactical terms, as

```
foldr g z [a,b,c,...,n] s =
     g a (foldr g z [b,c,...,n]) s
```

so when `g` is non-strict in its second argument, `s` can serve as a state being passed along from the left, even though we're folding on the right, as one example.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was trying to figure out whether this definition is unique and did not expect the use of Kleisli composition here. This answer really solve my doubt.

Comment: you're welcome. :)

Answer (score 4):

So the best way to understand it is by doing it. Below there's an implementation of `foldlM` using `foldl` instead of `foldr`. It is a good excercise, try it and come later to the solution I'd suggest. The example explain all the reasoning I've done to achieve it, which might be different from yours, and might be bias because I've already knew about using a function accumulator.

**Step 1**: Let's try to write `foldlM` in terms of `foldl`

```
-- this doesn't compile because f returning type is (m b) and not just (b) 
foldlM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b
foldlM f z0 xs = foldl f z0 xs 

-- So let substitute f by some undefined f'
foldlM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b
foldlM f z0 xs = foldl f' z0 xs
  where f' = undefined

-- cool, but f' should use f somehow in order to get the monadic behaviour
foldlM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b
foldlM f z0 xs = foldl f' z0 xs
  where f' b a = f somethingIDontkNow
```

Here you realize that `f'` is pure and you'd need to extract the result of `f` to type match. The only way to 'extract' a monadic value is with `>>=` operator, but such an operator needs to be wrap right after it is used.

So as a conclusion: Every time you end up with *I'd like to fully unwrap this monad*, just give up. Is not the right way

**Step 2**: Let's try to write `foldlM` in terms of `foldl` but first using `[]` as foldable, since it is easy to pattern match (i.e. we don't actually need to use `fold`)

```
-- This is not very hard. It is pretty standard recursion schema. :)
foldlM' :: (Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> [a] -> m b
foldlM' f z0 []     = return z0
foldlM' f z0 (x:xs) = f z0 x >>= \c -> foldlM' f c xs
```

Ok, that was easy. Let compare the definition with the usual `foldl` definition for lists

```
foldlM' :: (Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> [a] -> m b
foldlM' f z0 []     = return z0
foldlM' f z0 (x:xs) = f z0 x >>= \c -> foldlM' f c xs

myfoldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
myfoldl f z0 []     = z0
myfoldl f z0 (x:xs) = foldl f (f z0 x) xs
```

Cool!! they are pretty much the same. The trivial case is about the exact same thing. The recursive case is a little bit different, you'd like to write something more like: `foldlM' f (f z0 x) xs`. But is doesn't compile as in step 1, so you might think *OK, I don't want to apply `f`, just to hold such a computation and compose it with `>>=`. I'd like to write something more like* `foldlM' f (f z0 x >>=) xs` if it had sense...

**Step 3** Realize that what you want to accumulate is a function composition and not a result. (*here I am probably bias by the fact that I already knew it because you've posted it*).

```
foldlM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b
foldlM f z0 xs = foldl f' initFunc xs
  where initFunc = undefined :: b -> m b
        f'       = undefined :: (b -> m b) -> a -> (b -> m b) -- This type signature can be deduce because f' should be applied to initFunc and a's from t a.
```

By the type of `initFunc` and using our knowledge from step 2 (the recursive definition) we can deduce that `initFunc = return`. The definition of `f'` can be completed knowing that `f'` should use `f` and `>>=`.

```
foldlM :: (Foldable t, Monad m) => (b -> a -> m b) -> b -> t a -> m b
foldlM f z0 xs = foldl f' return xs z0
--                        ^^^^^^
--                        |- Initial value
  where f' b a = \bvalue -> b bvalue >>= \bresult -> f bresult a -- this is equivalent to (b >=> \result -> f result a) which captures the sequence behaviour of the implementation
--         ^      ^^^^^^                  ^^^^^^^
--         |      |                       |- This is the result of previous computation
--         |      |- f' should return a function b -> m b. Any time you have to return a function, start writing a lambda  
--         |- This b is the accumulated value and has type b -> m b
-- Following the types you can write this with enough practise
```

As you can see, it is not soooo difficult to do it. It needs practise, but I am not a professional haskell developer and I could do it myself, It is a matter of practise

Comment: I don't really see what makes a left fold easier to understand than a right fold here. The right fold is much more likely to produce a useful result for infinite structures and to be efficient for typical `Monad` instances.

Comment: @dfeuer The point of this is not to show an easier example, but to propose a suitable exercise for the OP and expose a reasoned argumentation of the solution, trying to proof that is not necessary to be a super-master haskeller in order to get such a solution. Digressions about efficiency aren't taken in account

Answer (score 3):

You don't need any specific knowledge in mathematics to write a function like `foldM`. I'm using Haskell in production for 4 years already, and I'm also struggling with understanding this definition of `foldM`. But that is mostly because it's poorly written. Please, don't take it as a personal fault if you can't understand some obscure code. Here is a more readable version of `foldlM`

```
foldlM
    :: forall t m a b .
       (Foldable t, Monad m)
    => (b -> a -> m b)  -- ^ Monadic action
    -> b                -- ^ Starting accumulator
    -> t a              -- ^ List of values
    -> m b              -- ^ Computation result inside a monad
foldlM f z xs = (foldr step pure xs) z
  where
    step :: a -> (b -> m b) -> b -> m b
    step cur next acc = do
        result <- f acc cur
        next result
```

This function is still not the easiest one. Mostly because it has non-typical usage of `foldr` where the intermediate accumulator is a function. But you can see a few mays that make such definition more readable:

1. Comments about function arguments.
2. Better argument names (still short and idiomatic, but they are at least more readable).
3. The explicit type signature of the function inside `where` (so you know the shape of the arguments).

After seeing such function, you can now perform *Equational reasoning technique* to expand the definition step-by-step and see how it works. Ability to come up with such functions comes with experience. I don't have strong mathematician skills, and this function is not a typical Haskell function. But the more practice you have, the better it gets :)